# Express Serve Not Running

Tags: node.js, express

I have purchased shared hosting from a2hosting.com
I used express web framework for API development in Nodejs. Currently when I run my app.js and try to run from browser then its giving 404 error every time:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.get("/", function(req,res){
   res.json({status:200});
 });

app.listen();
```

When I browse www.mydomain.com/app
it should return json response

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pass a port number as in:

```
app.listen(80)
```

or

```
app.listen(30001);
```

Then, the OS will assign a random port number which your client will not know and thus you can't contact that server from your client.

You should be using the default http port 80, a specific port both client and server agree to use or a port number assigned to you by your hosting provider.

---

You may also need to properly configure things at your hosting provider as described [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts#Integrating-a-Node.js-application-with-the-web-server) in your hosting provider's setup instructions so that incoming requests are directed to your local server.

---

Also, it looks like you need a specific type of "managed hosting" account at a2hosting.com in order to run node.js servers and need to select a port in a certain numeric range.